# How to change a url parameter to a slash?

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, get

I would like this:

post/view?id=619789185256734055595662

to become this:

post/view/619789185256734055595662

But nothing I've tried with .htaccess has worked so far. How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like you're calling your URL w/ GET parameters, no?
Is there a specific reason you're not just calling the URL with the parameter as part of it?
E.g. `window.location.href = myUrl + "/" + myId;`?

Also, please add what you've tried up until now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by URL Rewriting in PHP. This is a duplicate question. Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)